# Use GoogleDrive API: GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate to update file content, got 403 error

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-drive-api

I don't know how exactly use this API to update file content since I didn't get detail information from Document and DriveSample application. Thus, I tried to write it like:

```
GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLRUploadParameters
                    uploadParametersWithData:data
                                    MIMEType:@"binary/octet-stream"];
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate
                                 queryWithObject:cloudPreference
                                          fileId:cloudPreference.identifier
                                uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query
              completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *callbackTicket,
                                  GTLRDrive_File *uploadedFile,
                                  NSError *callbackError) {
                  if (callbackError == nil) {
                      NSLog(@"Updating file is finished!");
                  }
                  else {
                      NSLog(@"Failed to update file: %@", callbackError);
                  }
              }];
```

The error is:
**Failed to update file: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2265 72726f72 73223a5b ...**

Actually data is JSON format, I tried MIMEType with "applicaton/json" but still got 403 error. I can't google anything about this API with such error. The file is created by my application and I can download data from Google drive in my application. But I don't know what's wrong with my updating codes, Could anyone help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The questions was about the new Rest api (GTLR), "eschao" is referring to the old (obsolete) api.

I had exactly the same problem, but I fixed it by creating a new dummy GTLR_File variable and use that as the first param for the query.

Comment: Just to make the solution clear; in the previous version of GTL library, we were supposed to pass the existing GTLDriveFile object for the first parameter of query creation method to update an existing file, but in the new GTLR library, we have to create a new empty GTLRDrive_File object and pass it as the first paramter. In @eschao's code, replacing the `cloudPreference` with `[GTLRDrive_File object]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Error 403](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_daily_limit_exceeded) in Drive API might be caused by the ff:

- 403: Daily Limit Exceeded
- 403: User Rate Limit Exceeded
- 403: Rate Limit Exceeded
  -403: The user has not granted the app {appId} {verb} access to the file {fileId}
- 403: The user does not have sufficient permissions for file {fileId}
  -403: App with id {appId} cannot be used within the authenticated user's domain

Try using the code implementation stated in the docs with regard to [Updating Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files).

**Creating new files**

```
GTLServiceDrive *driveService = ...;
NSString *name = @"hello.txt";
NSString *content = @"Hello world";
NSString *mimeType = @"text/plain";

GTLDriveFile *metadata = [GTLDriveFile object];
metadata.name = name;

NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:mimeType];
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:metadata
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
[driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                     NSError *error) {
  if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"File %@", updatedFile);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
  }
}];
```

**To update an existing file**, follow the same process as creating a new file, but use the queryForFilesUpdatesWithObject method instead:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:file
                                                             fileId:file.identifier
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to see if I can use it as my expectation

Comment: if i just want to rename the name of pdf file how can i do it?. so how i get the data?

Comment: That would be 'name' from the [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) properties.